# XMLHttpRequest to grab database values (Wordpress)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I'm having issues getting my local Wordpress installation to properly grab data from a database. Im using xmlhttprequest to call a php file which has my database request and then sends it back. This all works on my local installation without Wordpress but once i moved it all over to a locla Wordpress im not getting any information back.

I was able to successfully add the Javascript XMLHttpRequest function to my php template and the function is called properly when I use the onchange event on dropdown select but doesnt seem to want to go over the other php request and start the db connection. Looking for any thoughts...thanks!

**Drop down select on Index.php**

```
<form method="get" action="./gardenguide.php">
          <table>
          <tr>
          <td>Hardiness Zone</td>
          <td>
            <select name="zone"  style="width:110px;" onchange="getVegetablesByZone(this.value)">
            <option selected disabled>Select</option>               
            <option value="2a">Zone 2a</option>
            <option value="2b">Zone 2b</option>
            <option value="3a">Zone 3a</option>
            <option value="3b">Zone 3b</option>
            <option value="4a">Zone 4a</option>
            <option value="4b">Zone 4b</option>
            <option value="5a">Zone 5a</option>
            <option value="5b">Zone 5b</option>
            <option value="6a">Zone 6a</option>
            <option value="6b">Zone 6b</option>
            <option value="7a">Zone 7a</option>
            <option value="7b">Zone 7b</option>
            <option value="8a">Zone 8a</option>
            <option value="8b">Zone 8b</option>
            <option value="9a">Zone 9a</option>
            <option value="9b">Zone 9b</option>
            <option value="10a">Zone 10a</option>
            <option value="10b">Zone 10b</option>
            <option value="11a">Zone 11a</option>
            <option value="11b">Zone 11b</option>
            <option value="12a">Zone 12a</option>
            <option value="12b">Zone 12b</option>
            <option value="13a">Zone 13a</option>
            <option value="13b">Zone 13b</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="results"><b></b></div>

        </form>
```

**JavaScript calling the XMLHTTP Request**

```
 function getVegetablesByZone(zone) {
if (zone == "") {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
    alert("works1");
    return;
} else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }

    };      
 }
```

**PHP called from Javascript**

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
echo "LOL";

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"plants");


$sql="SELECT plant_name FROM plants WHERE plant_id IN (SELECT fk_plant_id from hardinesszone WHERE zone = '$q')";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}

$display = "<table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border=1>
<tr>";

$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($i < 3)
{
    $display.= "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"v[]\" value=\"".$row['plant_name']."\"> " . $row['plant_name'] . "</td>";
}
else
{
    $display.= "</tr><tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"v[]\" value=\"".$row['plant_name']."\"> " . $row['plant_name'] . "</td>";
    $i=0;
   }

    $i=$i+1;
}

$display .= "</tr></table>";
$display .= "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-submit btn-lg\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Submit!\">";
echo $display;

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Did you change the username and password of DB when you moved it?

Comment: Database access doesnt seem to be the issue - if i put the database query on my first page im able to access the info. It seems to be the javascript is not calling the other php page... going crazy...